# Pig: flatten a tuple like bag

Tags: apache-pig

I have a tuple containing unknown number of fields. I want to flatten the tuple so that every element of the tuple creates a new row (the way Bag flattens)

e.g.
 **Input:**

```
student = { (A, B, (C, D, E, F)) }
```

**Output:**

```
student = { (A, B, C),
            (A, B, D),
            (A, B, E),
            (A, B, F),
          }
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks Himanshu for the formatting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, got it working!
Used LinkedIn's DataFu UDF library function TransposeTupleToBag to transpose tuples to bags, then flattened the bag.

Something like this:
    out = foreach student generate $0, $1, flatten(TransposeTupleToBag($2));